# D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_LINE in DirectX 12

Tags: line, directx, directx-12

Does anyone have an example of using D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_LINE in DirectX 12?

I tried using Frank Luna's D12 book as a guide but he does not cover it.

I tried google and the various D12 examples online but no luck.

Comment: Luna does cover this in _Game Programming for DX11_ where he implements a rain simulation with a particle system using `D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_LINE`. The example should be easily adapted for DX12.